# Can I use predictive text on jqgrid during form editing or adding?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid on which I am representing students. I want to enable predictive text to give suggestions to the user as they type the names of the student. If the name is LIKE any name in the database, I want to give them the option to select it. This may occur for the first and last names only.

In the suggestions, all need to do is send the student ID accross in the post of the form. If the value is not empty then I can work with the ID from there.

Any ideas as to how this may be achieved ?
Any resources you can point me to ?

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid has a built in "autocomplete" module that I believe you're looking for. You can see some direct php documentation [here](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_3130wm032.htm). This is assuming you're using the php API, however. Their full documentation of the PHP API [here](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/index.htm).

Comment: I am using Sprinf framework and jspx as the clientside technology, however i know a little PHP to under the tutorial, thanks.